# How to automatically display a table below the paragraph where its referenced

Tags: latex, ref

I am trying to format my latex document so all of the tables are figures will be displayed right after they are mentioned in the main article. The problem is I want to keep all of the tables and figures at the end of my latex document (code) for clarity.

The final result I have in mind is something like this:

Latex code--
Main
Tables/Figures

PDF--
Paragraph
Corresponding Tables
Paragraph
Corresponding Tables
...

Answer (score 0):

You could define each figure as a command; I've mocked up a quick example below. This would mean that you would either have to define your figures above where you call them (ew), or define them in another file which you then include (a bit better).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myfigure}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red] circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\myfigure

\end{document}
```

Comment: @PeiyaoLi Awesome! If it ends up working out for you, go ahead and mark the answer as accepted.